# Mysql - Order results by number of Id´s in another table

Tags: mysql

I have problem with my ordering of results in search.

I have two tables

Table photos (first table) where I have information about photos and every photo has ID.

When somebody clicks on result (photo) script saves information about it to second table.
Table (second table) looks like this

```
______________________
|ID of photo| keyword|
```

And sort results by count of photo IDs in second table

so `order by (something) + (something) + (count id´s of photo for phrase by user (keyword))`

For example:

In table are:

```
|id|keyword|
|5 |car    |
|5 |car    |
|6 |car    |
|6 |car    |
|2 |car    | 
|5 |car    |
```

Search query:

```
SELECT * FROM bx_photos_main WHERE (Title LIKE '%keyword%') OR (Desc LIKE '%keyword%') OR (Categories LIKE '%keyword%')order by (order) DESC LIMIT 0, 10;
```

When anyone try find "car" Photo 5 will be first, 6 second and third will be photo with id 2...Can somebody help me?

Structure
bx_photos_main

`ID   -    int(10)  -    UNSIGNED  -   AUTO_INCREMENT`

_bx_hledej (seccond table)
`id     - int(11)

keyword - varchar(20)`

Comment: Could you post the query(ies) you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To count (and order) by the number of photos per keyword, you could use a query like this:

```
 SELECT 
     photos.id,
     photos.Title,
     photos.Desc,
     photos.Categories
 FROM bx_photos_main photos
 LEFT OUTER JOIN _bx_hledej keywords
 ON keywords.id = photos.id
 WHERE (Title LIKE '%keyword%') OR (Desc LIKE '%keyword%') OR (Categories LIKE '%keyword%')
 GROUP BY keywords.keyword
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for fast answer! It´s look good, but i need part in order ORDER BY (this). Because, visitors can change ordering with button, and script change only this part.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. See updated query based on your actual db structure.